# gdb.execute blocks all the threads in python scripts

Tags: python, multithreading, gdb, gdb-python

I am scripting GDB with Python 2.7.

I am simply stepping instructions with `gdb.execute("stepi")`. If the debugged program is idling and waiting for user interaction, `gdb.execute("stepi")` doesn't return. If there is such a situation, I want to stop the debugging session without terminating gdb.

To do so, I create a thread that will kill the debugged process if the current instruction ran for more than x seconds:

```
from ctypes import c_ulonglong, c_bool
from os import kill
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import signal

# We need mutable primitives in order to update them in the thread
it = c_ulonglong(0) # Instructions counter
program_exited = c_bool(False)
t = Thread(target=check_for_idle, args=(pid,it,program_exited))
t.start()

while not program_exited.value:
    gdb.execute("si") # Step instruction
    it.value += 1

# Threaded function that will kill the loaded program if it's idling
def check_for_idle(pid, it, program_exited):
    delta_max = 0.1 # Max delay between 2 instructions, seconds
    while not program_exited.value:
        it_prev = c_ulonglong(it.value) # Previous value of instructions counter
        sleep(delta_max)
        # If previous instruction lasted for more than 'delta_max', kill debugged process
        if (it_prev.value == it.value):
            # Process pid has been retrieved before
            kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)       
            program_exited.value = True
    print("idle_process_end")
```

However, `gdb.execute` is pausing my thread... Is there another way to kill the debugged process if it is idling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, gdb.execute is pausing my thread

What is happening here is that `gdb.execute` does not release Python's global lock when calling into gdb.  So, while the gdb command executes, other Python threads are stuck.

This is just an oversight in gdb.  I've filed [a bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23615) for it.

> Is there another way to kill the debugged process if it is idling?

There is one other technique you can try -- I am not certain it will work.  Unfortunately this part of gdb is not fully fleshed out (at the present moment); so also feel free to file bug reports.

The main idea is to run gdb commands on the main thread -- but not from Python.  So, try writing your stepping loop using the gdb CLI, maybe like:

```
(gdb) while 1
> stepi
> end
```

Then your thread should be able to `kill` the inferior.  Another approach might be for your thread to inject a gdb command into the main loop using `gdb.post_event`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and for filing that bug report. My script is meant to do bulk asm processing in order to build a database, thus I can't use the CLI because the script needs to be fully automated. Also, I can't use `gdb.post_event` because I need to retrieve the outputs of the `gdb.execute` commands in a string, sequentially.